# Why my Symfony Front Controller doesn't work?

Tags: symfony1, front-controller

I have this:

```
  web/index.php
  web/myapp_dev.php
```

I declare with the same code:

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('myapp', 'dev', true);
```

for modules, I have:

```
  login with index
```

If I call:  http://localhost/myapp_dev.php/login/  it works.
for http://localhost/  it works.   And the any link in the index template is correctly pointing to http://localhost/module/action.  e.g. http://localhost/login/  (not http://localhost/myapp_dev.php/login , that's good)
but if I call http://localhost/login/  it doesn't work.  and return 404.

What goes wrong?  What should I set?

Comment: Do you have enable the rewrite rule?

Comment: Did you clear your cache after adding the routing rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptoms you describe typically indicate a missing mod_rewrite rule.

Make sure that your Apache instance has mod_rewrite enabled.

http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/enable-mod-rewrite-on-apache

Comment: yah.. at last, I found out it is the apache config that has the mod_rewrite module turn off.  thanks a lot. :)